# CSS. Center inline-block. Don't center content

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrap{
  width:800px;
  background: beige;
  padding:20px
}

.contactForm__headerWrap{
  border:1px solid darkkhaki;
  width:100%;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
}

.contactForm__headerContainer{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.contactForm__headerContainer_header{
  text-align:left;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

.contactForm__headerContainer_header-big{
  border:1px solid darkorchid;
  font-size:20px
}

.contactForm__headerContainer_header-small{
  border:1px solid darkorange;
  font-size:14px;
  text-aling: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="contactForm__headerWrap">
    <div class="contactForm__headerContainer">
        <div class="contactForm__headerContainer_header contactForm__headerContainer_header-big">big header</div>
        <div class="ccontactForm__headerContainer_header contactForm__headerContainer_header-small">small header</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I center an inline-block div, without using text-align?

Ok, i added code snippet and show the problem. My small header centered left now and i want to aligin it to left of inline-block. I don't want  set static width of  `contactForm__headerContainer`. 
That's possible?

[image: Scheme]

Comment: Why don't you want to use `text-align`? It's the most efficient method to align inline elements. If it's because it also centers the text in the `inline-block` element, then you can always declare a `text-align` rule for this element specifically that will qualify over the parent element's rule. So `text-align: center` on parent, and `text-align: left` on nested inline-block element.

Comment: If i using `text-align` i don't know how to aling to left  small header(second). Look at scheme image

Comment: I have, and that's why I suggested declaring `text-align: left` on that element (small header element as you refer to as, which I assume is the block with the red border). So to clarify: `text-align; center` on element with green border, then `text-align: left` on element with red border; try that. Otherwise consider displaying the red border element as a block with its margins set to `auto` and declare a `maximum-width` of a value equal to width you need this element to be.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.contactForm__headerWrap {
  text-align: center;
}
.contactForm__headerContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactForm__headerWrap">
  <div class="contactForm__headerContainer">
    <span class="contactForm__headerContainer_header contactForm__headerContainer_header-big">ЗАГОЛОВОК НОМЕР ОДИН</span>
    <span class="ccontactForm__headerContainer_header contactForm__headerContainer_header-small">ПОДЗАГОЛОВОК</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this (works for block element also):

```
.center-horizontal {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 }
```

Explanation: left:50% will position the element starting from the center of containing parent, so you want to pull it back by half of its width with transform: translateX(-50%)

Note1: Be sure to set the the position of containing parent to position: relative; if the parent is absolutely positioned put a 100% width and height, 0 padding and margin div inside it and give it position: relative

Note2: Can also be modified for vertical centering with

top:50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the below to center the inner div

```
  margin: 0 auto;
```